# Строки и их использование

Tags: c++, строки

Как лучше всего объявить строку и работать с ней:

`string name`, `char* name` или `char name[10]`, например

Comment: Лучше попробовать все три варианта. И остановиться на первом.

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно вам нужно. Обычно проще всего - `string`.

Comment: даже если вам где то нужен char* , то string::c_str()  возвращает const char*,  так что  лучше класс конечно

Comment: Если для конкретной задачи достаточно именно `char name[10]`, то очевидно это и надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко, то по-моему в большенстве случаев лучше использовать `std::string`, далее подробнее:

У массива символов есть определенные недостатки:

- Необходимо самостоятельно следить за выходом за границу массива
- При динамическом размещении строки в куче (при использовании `new char[]`) необходимо всегда помнить о необходимости освободить память
- При размещении в стеке (типа `char s[100]`) строка всегда будет занимать в память 100 байт, даже если хранимая строка будет длинной 10 байт
- Определение длинны строки состоит в переборе символов до обнаруженмя '\0'

Класс `std::string` лишен этих недостатков: нам не надо задумываться об освобождении памяти (она будет освобождена автоматически деструктором), не надо заранее резервировать побольше памяти в стеке для длинных строк и потом следить за выходом за границу массива, а длина хранимой в объекте строки хранится в объектае и доступна мгновенно.

Кроме того хочется добавить про отличие char[] и char*: при объявлении строки

```
char array_string[] = "string";
```

в стеке будет создан массив символов, в который из строкового литерала (хранящегося, кстати, где-то совершенно в другом месте) будет скопирована строка `"string"`. Вы можете писать в этот массив, изменять его содержимое.

Однако при объявлении

```
char *pointer_string = "string";
```

В стеке будет выделена память под указатель на `char`, в который будет записан адрес строкового литерала. Изменять память строкового литерала крайне нежелательно.

Кроме того банальная `sizeof(array_string)` вернет Вам количество символов в строке, когда как `sizeof(pointer_string)` вернет размер указателя.

Answer (score 1):

```
string name;
```

Лучший выбор.

```
char *name1;
```

Для С но можно и в С++.
Я бы вообще не советовал опасная вещь.

```
char name2[N];
```

Хороший вариант для strcpy_s и прочего(но смысл если в string всё это есть)

```
string s1,s2;
s1="HELLO";
s2="WORLD";
cout<< s1+" "+s2<<endl;
s1=s2+"!";
if(s1==s2)
    cout<<"error"<<endl;
```